# how to add data in DB in any charset?

Tags: php, mysql, html

When I add data to my db Russian letter are converted into some kind of symbols like this: Ð´Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ð´. Same with Georgian language. I use PHP to insert data from web to db. In html charset is utf-8 and also in database Collation is set to utf8_general_ci. How can i fix it?
[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2uBC.png)

Comment: Is your connection utf-8, too?

Comment: Can you tell me to to set it to utf-8?

Comment: found it. thanks <3